# Magento 2.3.3 upgrade

Tags: magento2

i am getting this error i am using ced/creditlimit extension when i open grid Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context","1":"#1

Answer (score 1):

Search for it and just remove context argument from listing.

```
<argument name="context" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context</argument>
        <argument name="namespace" xsi:type="string">some_namespace</argument>
</argument>
```

!!! IMPORTANT !!!
I don't know for sure what it previously do, so test listing behavior first.

Anyway, that works for me fine.